# PageViews are attached to the same PageController

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have problems when displaying 2 PageViews on 1 screen it seems. Below is my app: the calendar weeks timeline is PageView and content below it also needs to be PageView.

[image: screenshot]

Now both PageViews need to talk to each other - when scrolling bottom content pageview I want upper view to change white circle selection, and finally flip the page, when coming to the end.

So I use

```
calendarPageView.controller.jumpToPage(pageForDate);
```

(or nextPage() method) and this is what I get:

> The page property cannot be read when multiple PageViews are attached to the same PageController.
>   package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': Failed assertion: line 101 pos 7: 'positions.length == 1

It seems they for some reason use the same PageController? Any thoughts how to solve it?

Comment: Just putting it out here if anyone comes here: i just needed to hot restart my app and the error went... seems like some debug cache issue :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figgured it out! :) For your sake, make sure you construct your PageView with creating it's own instance of PageController, e.g.:

```
new PageView.builder(
   ...,
   controller: new PageController()
);
```

So you don't run into this issue. It seems that by default PageViews share the controller for some reason.